# Python port scanner exception problems

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, exception, port-scanning

```
import socket
import sys
import threading
import concurrent.futures
import pyfiglet,time
import colorama
from colorama import Fore

ascii_banner = pyfiglet.figlet_format("Port Scanner")
print(ascii_banner)

print(Fore.GREEN + "Stat time: " + time.asctime())
start = time.perf_counter()

my_file = open("List of OpenPorts.txt", "w")
my_file.write("Port Scanner \n\n")


colorama.init()

print_lock = threading.Lock()

ip = input(Fore.BLUE + "Enter the IP to scan: ")

def scan(ip, port):
    scanner = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    scanner.settimeout(1)
    try:
        scanner.connect((ip, port))
        scanner.close()
        with print_lock:
            print(Fore.BLUE + f"Port[{port}]" + Fore.GREEN + " Opened")
            my_file.write(f'Port{port} is open \n')
    except socket.gaierror:
        print("Invalid Hostname. Please enter in a valid hostname")
        my_file.write("Invalid Hostname. Please enter in a valid hostname")




with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=100) as executor:
    for port in range(1025):
        executor.submit(scan, ip, port + 1)

finish = time.perf_counter()
print("End time: " +time.asctime())
print(f'Finished in {round(finish - start, 2)} second(s)')
my_file.close()
```

**Im trying to make the code print only one exception when it encounters a problem. But when the code runs it prints the error code multiple times , I'm guessing it prints it  1025 times because of the threading code . Im not sure how to make it print only one time and end the code afterwards.
**

Answer (score 0):

Because every thread is checking for the same error (invalid hostname), if we run `scan()` once with a random port number we can check for the invalid hostname before spinning up all 1025 threads.

```
import socket
import sys
import threading
import concurrent.futures
import pyfiglet,time
import colorama
from colorama import Fore

ascii_banner = pyfiglet.figlet_format("Port Scanner")
print(ascii_banner)

print(Fore.GREEN + "Stat time: " + time.asctime())
start = time.perf_counter()

my_file = open("List of OpenPorts.txt", "w")
my_file.write("Port Scanner \n\n")


colorama.init()

print_lock = threading.Lock()

ip = input(Fore.BLUE + "Enter the IP to scan: ")

def scan(ip, port):
    scanner = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    scanner.settimeout(1)
    try:
        scanner.connect((ip, port))
        scanner.close()
        with print_lock:
            print(Fore.BLUE + f"Port[{port}]" + Fore.GREEN + " Opened")
            my_file.write(f'Port{port} is open \n')
    except socket.gaierror:
        with print_lock:
            print("Invalid Hostname. Please enter in a valid hostname")
            my_file.write("Invalid Hostname. Please enter in a valid hostname")
            return False
    except ConnectionRefusedError:
        pass

    return True



with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=100) as executor:
    # Random value
    if not scan(ip, 10000):
        exit(0)

    for port in range(1025):
        executor.submit(scan, ip, port + 1)

finish = time.perf_counter()
print("End time: " +time.asctime())
print(f'Finished in {round(finish - start, 2)} second(s)')
my_file.close()
```

Comment: thank you so much. I deeply appreciate this .

Comment: @gummyotter If you think my answer adequately addresses your question you can mark it as the “selected answer” which will help others in the future with a similar issue. But no worries if not - glad I could help :)